# Django, select_related or prefetch_related when updating

Tags: django, caching

Suppose you have a shopping cart and cart has many item lines.

For retrieving data, you could use `select_related or prefetch_related` fine.

However there are apis which update the lines data (you might want to change quantity for an item).

When you update a line, the prefetched lines would be invalid.
How do you manage update and still get the benefit of `select_related / prefetch_related`?

Is there a better way than manually tracking the code where update might occur and re-valuate the `select_related / prefetch_related` everytime when data changes ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by invalid, correct me if I am wrong, the select_related/prefetch happens when you query, they are merely strategy of joining tables(selected_related) or python prefetch(prefetch_related) to avoid N+1 problem, it doesn't not "cache" anything.

Comment: yeah, I think I have to refine my question a bit.. thanks for the input..